# What is the name of this font?

Tags: font-identification, web-fonts

I downloaded a font to design this logo many months ago. Since then, I have had to  reinstalled my operative system, which meant a lot of information disappeared along with the font I downloaded.

The company responsible for printing out the logo, say they cant print it out as an image but as text, they need the font name to proceed. The problem is that I cant seem to remember the font name.

Kindly find the image with the font in subject below.

Anyone help would be greatly appreciated![image: Logo of the hotel]

Comment: 90% of all well designed logos are not "fonts". Any printer stating they "can't print the logo as an image" is a printer I'd seriously question.

Comment: You designed the logo...did you create a vector (outlines) version of it to create the image you are showing us? If so, the printer should be able to print that just fine.

Comment: I second @DA01 what the printer might mean, is that if you have sent them a pdf with the logo as a font - and not as an outline - they would need either the font embedded, or the font as an outline.

Comment: Another means for font identification (not perfect, but still an option) is to use a web service like "**What the font**" - http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Comment: This is what I used. Cursive fonts aren't particularly easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called [Miss Le Gatees Regular](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/sudtipos/miss-le-gatees/regular/).

[image: Miss Le Gatees Regular from MyFonts]

[image: Miss Le Gatees Regular from MyFonts]

However, the roses are not part of the font, obviously. So you're going to need some sort of image, preferably vector. But at least the letters can be recreated easily.